# How to filter objects after using groupby?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to display an average working time by occupation and gender. So I have three columns - occupation, sex, hours-per-week. I have displayed this using a bar chart, but I need only men to be showed.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data', header=None)
df.columns = ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num', 'marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex',
          'capital-gain', 'capital-loss', 'hours-per-week', 'native-country', 'income']

df.groupby(['occupation','sex'])['hours-per-week'].mean().plot('bar')
```

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8D20.png)

Comment: Try `df.groupby(['occupation','sex'])['hours-per-week'].mean().xs('Male', 0, 1).plot('bar')`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately with a KeyError

Comment: That's why we need sample data.  Read [mcve]

Comment: You can filter the data before calling groupby.

Comment: I have added a data set to the description of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.query('sex == " Male"')\
  .groupby(['occupation','sex'])['hours-per-week'].mean().plot('bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the dataframe by sex with:

```py
df[df.sex == ' Male']
```

Don't forget the space since your data has one before "Male" and "Female".

Comment: I actually did this and it worked. Thanks a lot for help! 

    df1 = df[df.sex == ' Male'] 
    df1.groupby(['occupation','sex'])['hours-per-week'].mean().plot('bar')

Comment: I didn't know that this data set has a space before values